# Close searchview programmatically

Tags: android

I have a searchview.Here is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE); 
    searchView = (SearchView)searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.hint)); //if you want a custom hint
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    EditText et = (EditText)searchView.findViewById(searchView.getContext().getResources()
            .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null));
    et.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

    if (hideSearchButton == false) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_shuffle).setVisible(true);
    }else{
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_shuffle).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
    }
    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean queryTextFocused) {
            if(!queryTextFocused) {
            }
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

I have to close this searchivew from another method.How can I do this ? I researched another questions but not worked.

Comment: MenuItem.collapseActionView()

Comment: The method collapseActionView() is undefined for the type SearchView

Comment: not SearchView but MenuItem, MenuItem has method called collapseActionView()

Comment: menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).collapseActionView(); not worked.

Comment: it works, just tested that

Comment: add for example searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(listener); and call it in onQueryTextSubmit method

Comment: Can you give an example for this :  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(listener); ?

Comment: what example? just call searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(listener) and implement the listener

Comment: I want example for listener.

Comment: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener listener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() { ...

Comment: can you send me your test code ? I will review it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vJ4KUBC2

Comment: Thank you.It worked.If you write an answer for this question I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `MenuItem.collapseActionView()` in your case searchItem.collapseActionView()

Comment: I do not know why, but on some devices works searchView.onActionViewCollapsed(), on other - searchMenuItem.collapseActionView()